# How to take quantity based pricing in save search netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I have to create a save search and fetch pricing of items which is quantity based. How to do that. For fetching unit price, I use the following formula.

```
DECODE({inventorylocation},'WH29',{locationquantityavailable})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK quantity pricing is not available in search joins/columns. You may alternatively load the record and get quantity pricing.

You can matrix field APIs to get pricing information after you load the record.

Note, that the pricing matrix id varies depending on whether multiprice and multicurrency features are enabled.

**[Update]**

There is this `pricing` join, which is not documented.

In the Search UI it has useful fields like: `currency`, `minimuquantity` and `maximumquantity`.

From the script I could get value for additonal fields like:
`unitprice`, `pricelevel` and `quantityrange`

Comment: Yeah, i did that .. and i was doing the same .. but I thought It could be better if i can do this in save search itself as loading record slows the script. Thanks for your answer prasun. You always help ..

Comment: @prasun Dude! I don't think it's very ethical to correct your accepted wrong answer with answers supplied by others.

Comment: @bknights I didn't mean that, I kept the original answer as not available and added in update. If answer gets unaccepted I can delete it.

Answer (score 4):

To add an example:

```
var itemIds = [...]; // for some set of items
var itemPrices = nlapiSearchRecord('item', null,
  [
    new nlobjSearchFilter('internalid', null, 'anyof', itemIds),
    new nlobjSearchFilter('currency', 'pricing', 'is', '1'), // use this line if you have multiple currencies. normally 1 is USD but this varies by account.
    new nlobjSearchFilter('pricelevel', 'pricing', 'is', '5'), // default online price level id. You can use any id.
    // new nlobjSearchFilter('customer', 'pricing', 'is', customerId) // if you are getting the prices for a particular customer
   ],[
     new nlobjSearchColumn('unitprice', 'pricing'),
     new nlobjSearchColumn('quantityrange', 'pricing')
]);
```

**Note:**

You probably want to limit your list of items because even this example will return a row count that is the # of items * # of price breaks. Without the currency and price level filters you can quickly use up the default search result limit (# of items * # of price levels * # of currencies * # of price breaks) and end up having to use slower strategies for returning the information.

Answer (score 1):

When you turn on Multiple Prices and/or Quantity Pricing feature in NetSuite, there is an additional record joined to the item record called Pricing ({pricing}).

This new pricing join has {quantityrange}, {maximumquantity}, and {minimumquantity}.  You can use these fields to add to your query of the item record, or you can go direct from the Pricing record which has a join to the item recording using field {item}.