# Pulling Quantity Pricing through Suitescript?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Looking to see if anyone has an example to pull Quantity Pricing from an item record with SuiteScript? I haven't been able to find anything online and don't even know how that would build out if it was SuiteScripted (since the qty is different per item). Anyone have anything that can show me how to do this?

Comment: See my example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39869486/how-to-take-quantity-based-pricing-in-save-search-netsuite/39878660#39878660

Answer (score 1):

Part of the issue with supplying sample code is that the code will be different depending on whether you also have multiple currencies available.

If you only have one currency you can get the prices for the price breaks as follows, The endpriceX values indicate the last quantity the associated price is applicable to:

```
strprice1 = myitem.getFieldValue('pricequantity1');
var valprice1 = myitem.getLineItemMatrixValue('price', 'price', lineno, 1);
valprice1 = parseFloat(valprice1);


var strprice2 = myitem.getFieldValue('pricequantity2');
var valprice2 = myitem.getLineItemMatrixValue('price', 'price', lineno, 2);
var endprice1 = parseInt(strprice2) - 1;
valprice2 = parseFloat(valprice2);


var strprice3 = myitem.getFieldValue('pricequantity3');
var endprice2 = parseInt(strprice3) - 1;
var valprice3 = myitem.getLineItemMatrixValue('price', 'price', lineno, 3);
valprice3 = parseFloat(valprice3);


var strprice4 = myitem.getFieldValue('pricequantity4');
var endprice3 = parseInt(strprice4) - 1;
var valprice4 = myitem.getLineItemMatrixValue('price', 'price', lineno, 4);
valprice4 = parseFloat(valprice4);


var strprice5 = myitem.getFieldValue('pricequantity5');
var endprice4 = parseInt(strprice5) - 1;
var valprice5 = myitem.getLineItemMatrixValue('price', 'price', lineno, 5);
valprice5 = parseFloat(valprice5);
```