# How to get an item price using SuiteScript 2?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Using SuiteScript 2 in a Suitelet, how can I determine a price given a price list internal id, an item internal id and a currency (probably internal id)?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the N/search module. Load/create a search within your script for the record type 'pricinggroup' and add criteria for the item and currency.

I would look at SuiteAnswer 63120 for further details. Hope it helps!

Comment: That SuiteAnswer is about pricinggroup, but I used successfully a search on item joined with pricing, as suggested at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39878660